# Calculating hours between the two dates as per range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two columns startDate and endDate
I need to calculate number of hours count from 0 to 23 between these dates
Example, start date is 2000-12-05 10:00:00 and end date is 2001-01-15 15:00:00
I need to calculate how many times hour 0 to 23 occurred between these two dates in python

I took the difference between the dates and calculated hours from the difference.
After which I plan to extract start hour from startDate till startDateHour * hours to get the endHour
and iterate through a dictionary to increase the count, but is there any other approach with which I can do this?

```
df['diff'] = df['endDate'] - df['startDate']
df['hours']= df['diff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> df['diff'] = df['endDate'] - df['startDate']
>>> df['hours'] = df['diff'].dt.components.hours
```

Considering these are `pd.Timedelta` objects.

```
>>> idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ts':ts, 'ts_2':ts + pd.Timedelta(hours=1)})
>>> df

                   ts                ts_2
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 01:00:00
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00 2018-01-01 03:00:00
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00 2018-01-01 04:00:00
4 2018-01-01 04:00:00 2018-01-01 05:00:00
>>> df['hour'] = (df['ts_2'] - df['ts']).dt.components.hours

>>> df

                   ts                ts_2  hour
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 01:00:00     1
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00     1
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00 2018-01-01 03:00:00     1
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00 2018-01-01 04:00:00     1
4 2018-01-01 04:00:00 2018-01-01 05:00:00     1
```

Comment: This will not give hour starting 0 right? I want something like 0: 15, 1: 20, 3: 20, ....23: 20 which is hour count for each hour

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

 X = (datetime.strptime(2020-01-05 01:19:49, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') - 
      datetime.strptime(2020-01-02 06:12:44, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s'))

 print(X)
```